# How to change two font awesome (CSS) classes dynamically using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, font-awesome

I have used font awesome CSS on a dropdown button to show plus and minus icon, I wanted to change the CSS from plus to minus when the dropdown is expanded and vice versa.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="expand" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> {{expression}}</a>
```

Need to change the fa fa-plus-circle class to fa fa-minus-circle class when dropdown expanded and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

It's a BAD practice to have `ng-model` on an element which is not used for  input from the user. It should be used when you want to provide two way binding. 
You could use `ng-class` to add a class conditionally

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="expand" 
  btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" 
  btn-checkbox-false="false"
  ng-click="expand=!expand">
    <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-plus-circle': !expand, 'fa-minus-circle': expand}"></i> 
      {{expression}}
</a>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Pradvaarcruz glad to help you..Thanks :)